# Recursively encode video files in many directories

Tags: bash, loops, file, recursion, ffmpeg

I'd like to encode video files in many directories in one go. In each directory when there is at least one `*.mp4` file `ffmpeg` application should be run with correct arguments. Say a video file is named `01_file.mp4`. I want the output file to be in the same directory as the source is located with name suffix `processed` at the end of filename but before extension`. So the source` 01_file.mp4`would be saved as`01_file_processed.mp4`.
I'm quite close to the correct solution. Here's my one-liner:

`find -mindepth 2 -type f ! -path '*processed.mp4' -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i "$1" -vf fps=23.976025 "${1%/*}/${1##*/}_processed"' _ {} \;`

I'm getting the error from `ffmpeg` since the output file is not correct. Instead of correct path ending with `01_file_processed.mp4` the file is `01_file.mp4_processed`. I believe the error is in the following part `${1%/*}/output/${1##*/}"`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to separate dirname from basename, if the only thing you do with this splitting is to reconcatenate it?

I feel that you have tried to imitate another code that has another objective.

In your case, if I understand correctly, you don't need to extract basename nor dirname. But you want to remove the extension to add a `_processed` before it.

Which is quite easy to do, with your technique, since you know the extension is `.mp4`. So just remove the trailing `.mp4`, exactly as you've removed the trailing `/*` to extract dirname. And then replace that `.mp4` by what you want, namely, `_processed.mp4`

```bash
find -mindepth 2 -type f ! -path '*processed.mp4' -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i "$1" -vf fps=23.976025 "${1%.mp4}_processed.mp4"' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've got Bash version 4.3 or later, try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob extglob globstar nullglob
for mp4file in */**/!(*_processed).mp4; do
    echo ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i "$mp4file" -vf fps=23.976025 "${mp4file%.mp4}_processed.mp4"
done
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` processes such files by default.
  - `extglob` enables "extended globbing" (including patterns like `!(*_processed).mp4`).  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).
  - `globstar` enables the use of `**` to match paths recursively through directory trees.  This option was introduced with Bash 4.0 (released in 2009) but it is dangerous to use in versions before 4.3 (released in 2014) because it follows symlinks.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${mp4file%.mp4}`.
- Remove the `echo` if you are happy that the code will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Untested and assuming your file names don't contain newlines:

```
sfx='mp4'
while IFS= read -r orig; do
    proc="${orig%%.$sfx}_processed.$sfx"
    ffmpeg ...whatever... "$orig" > "$proc"
done < <( find -mindepth 2 -type f ! -path "*processed.$sfx" -name "*.$sfx" {} + )
```